# Passing data to Horizontal Bar Highchart.js showing only one record in codeigniter

Tags: json, highcharts, foreach, bar-chart, codeigniter-3

im really confuse how to pass data from controller to horizontal bar bcz this is my first time dealing with charts and i hope someone can help me n tell me the best way to fetch data n pass it to chart .

i tried using foreach in view and then echo inside chart script ..when i use Print_R i can see all data .. but when i put it inside the horizontal-bar Chart it only give me 1 record .  [here is the screenshot of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWbeD.png)

and this is what i did in controller and view :

**Controller**

```
 public function index()
{
    $data['db1'] = $this->m_mds->isiChart();
    $data['content'] = 'tempelates/MDS/content';
    $data['chart'] = 'tempelates/MDS/chart';
    $this->load->view('tempelate',$data);
}
```

and here is the foreach in view :

```
<figure class="highcharts-figure">
   <div id="container"></div>
</figure>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>       
<?php foreach ($db1->result_array() as $key) {
          $nmbrg= $key['NAMA_BRG'];
          $oos=$key['OOS'];
          $kurang= $key['kurang_4'];
          $osa=$key['OSA'];
         }?>
<script>
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'bar',
    options3d: { enabled: true, }
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Stacked bar chart'
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: [<?php echo json_encode($nmbrg)?> ]
  },
  yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    title: {
      text: 'Total fruit consumption'
    }
  },
  legend: {
    reversed: true
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      stacking: 'normal'
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'OOS',
    data: [<?php echo json_encode($oos)?>]
  }, {
    name: '<4',
    data: [<?php echo json_encode($kurang)?>]
  }, {
    name: 'OSA',
    data: [<?php echo json_encode($osa)?>]
  }]
});
</script>
```

what i want to do is.. make the output of foreach like this

```
[{"namabrg":"YOLITE C+100 STRAWBERRY ","oos":1719,"kurang":4264,"osa":40100},{"namabrg":"YOLITE KIDS 70 ML BND 4 ORI ","oos":2,"kurang":3,"osa":162}]
```

and pass all data comes from foreach to horizontal bar Chart.

Comment: Is this an output that you want to achieve? https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/1td6qkg5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your PHP code block to this: (Put inidvidual values into array and implode array values to lists)

```
<?php 
$nmbrg_values = array();
$oos_values = array();
$kurang_values = array();
$osa_values = array();

foreach ($db1->result_array() as $key) {
    $nmbrg_values[] = $key['NAMA_BRG'];
    $oos_values[] = $key['OOS'];
    $kurang_values[] = $key['kurang_4'];
    $osa_values[] = $key['OSA'];
}
$nmbrg = implode(", ", $nmbrg_values);
$oos = implode(", ", $oos_values);
$kurang = implode(", ", $kurang_values);
$osa = implode(", ", $osa_values);
?>
```

Comment: Thnx for ur reply ..and it works now .. @adam P.  do u prefer ajax to call data for chart rather than using php ? i really want to use ajax but i dont know how . could u gimme some clue of it ? ill really happy if u do :)